# What is the difference between derivation and entailment?

Tags: comparison, logic, norvig-russell

In section 7.3 of the book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://cs.calvin.edu/courses/cs/344/kvlinden/resources/AIMA-3rd-edition.pdf#page=261) (3rd edition), it's written

> An inference algorithm that derives only entailed sentences is called **sound** or **truth-preserving**.

> The property of **completeness** is also desirable: an inference algorithm is complete if it can derive any sentence that is entailed.

However, this does not make much sense to me. I'd like someone to kindly elaborate on this.

Comment: I've the same problem, reading same book.
This helped me a little bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xL0kNw5TudI
let me know if you get something better.